# Bind Button Content to DatePicker SelectedDate

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, datepicker, controltemplate

I have the following DatePicker Control:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateFor}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonDatePicker}"/>
```

The `ButtonDatePicker` style is defined as below:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonDatePicker" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, Path=SelectedDate.Date}"/>

                    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="False"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to bind the `Content` property of the `PART_Button` Button to the `SelectedDate.Date` property of the DatePicker itself. I tried like this:

```
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, Path=SelectedDate.Date}"
```

but it doesn't work. The content of the Button is "Show calendar" (I didn't set this) all the time like in the picture below.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Button to use a TextBlock for its Content:

```
<Button x:Name="PART_Button">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, Path=SelectedDate.Date}"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Combined With the proper StringFormat statement your answer is what I need :) Thanks.